# SVG icons from PNG

Tags: svg

I need to convert PNG icons into SVG format. What size should the initial PNGs be? Do I need to make the icons smaller (they will be 30 x 30 px on the site) before I save them as SVGs?

Comment: This is not possible: SVG and PNG files represent different things. PNG files contain raster graphics and SVG files contain vector graphics. While it is possible to render vector graphics as raster (i.e. convert SVG to PNG), it is not possible to convert from raster graphics to vector graphics (i.e. convert from PNG to SVG). It's a one-way, destructive operation. It's like trying to "decrypt" a user's password from a salted hash. There is software that attempts to recreate vectors based on interpreting raster graphics but it's imperfect.

Comment: Yes, I am going to turn it into vector. But what size should the canvas be in illustrator?

Comment: If you are using illustrator and trace > expand you can use any size you want. If you take a look at the font awesome icons they are using a 500/500 svg canvas

Comment: It seems to increase file size, I wonder why